# How to provide "Share" link from my app to whatsup, facebook, etc

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to allow the users to share a content from within my app to others social app such as whatsup, facebook, sms, etc...
I heard about the uiactivityviewcontroller, but not shure this is the right way to accomplish that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample extension with code https://docs.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/Share/ does that help any?  It doesn't do much, but it shows the structure, you'd need your own code to do the actual sharing